# ORA-00913: too many values

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, oracle11g, ora-00913

getting `ORA-00913:` too many values. don't know how to resolve this issue please anyone could help me?

```
con2 = DriverManager.getConnection("Jdbc:Oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE", "system",
                "oracle123");
        File image=new File("E:/Users/ganesh/Desktop/line.jpg");
        String sql="insert into blobtab values(?,?)";  
        pstmt=con2.prepareStatement(sql);
        pstmt.setString(1,"akshita");
        fis=new FileInputStream(image);
        pstmt.setBinaryStream(2,(InputStream)fis,(int)(image.length()));
        int s = pstmt.executeUpdate();
        if (s > 0) {
            System.out.println("Image Uploaded successfully !");
        } else {
            System.out.println("unsucessfull to upload image.");
        }
        con2.close();
        pstmt.close();
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I place large (or at least nontrivial) BLOBs into Oracle with JDBC?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3189125/how-do-i-place-large-or-at-least-nontrivial-blobs-into-oracle-with-jdbc)

Answer (score 3):

This would suggest that your blobtab table didn't have two columns in it (or if there's a trigger on the table, check the DML being fired recursively in those for the same problem).

```
insert into blobtab values(?,?)
```

eg:

```
SQL> create table foo(id number);

Table created.

SQL> insert into foo values (1, 2);
insert into foo values (1, 2)
           *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00913: too many values
```

check your table. also you should always put explicit column names on your insert (in case someone adds default or nullable columns later on. i.e. always do:

```
insert into blobtab (col1, col2) values(?,?)
```

where `col1` `col2` are your real column names.

Answer (score 2):

**the number of column  would have been less than the paraemeter/argument passed**

eg: insert into insert **into foo(name , age) values (?,?,?)** and then preparedStatment object insert

Since there is **2 column and value have 3 parameter** 
therefore ,
 ORA-00913: too many values